# Run a collection for GET and POST requests specified in a single data file in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, c#, api, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to run multiple iterations of a Collection on postman for different API calls using data driven approach. The collection file checks for a response status of 200 OK and time elapsed < 500 ms for the requests specified in the data file.

The data file contains a few GET and a few POST requests. The collection runs fine if all the requests specified in the data file are POST. I would like to run the collection for POST/GET request.

Is there any way that we can update the request type while running a collection?

I get following error message for the GET request:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is a Postman issue, I think your GET URI is wrong. You can mix any number of different HTTP verbs in a Collection and use CollectionRunner.

Comment: The URI is correct. I get correct output for the GET request when sent individually.

Comment: When you do it individually does the request match what is logged by the collection runner? Are the data items merged in correctly? I know for a fact you can mix verbs in a run.

Comment: Also, I tried a work around by sending a dummy/bogus request in the collection file, which in its test file sets the next request to POST/GET based on the method mentioned in the data file. This approach works fine but with more number of API calls in the data file, it consumes a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, the individual request matches the request logged by the collection runner.

Comment: What's with the dollar signs in the URI?